# Strange interaction with directive's link function and isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive:

```
ngModule.directive('customer', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.meta = 'bar';
        }
    };
});
```

And template:

```
<h1>Customers</h1>
<div data-customer>
  <div>Meta: {{ meta }}</div>
</div>
```

I expect 'Meta: bar' to appear in the template. However, only 'Meta :' appears. Note that if I set 'scope: true', it does appear.

Why does the value not bind correctly when I use an isolate scope?

Comment: Isolate scopes are isolated to the single DOM node they are attached to.

Comment: isolate scopes won't work on html that isn't compiled by directive using `template` , `templateUrl` or `$compile`. Samples shown aren't clear if this is the case or not but assume that since directive has none of those that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

That binding references controller scope.  If you want to display something attached to directive scope, insert them into the template of the directive, like this:

```
ngModule.directive('customer', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.meta = 'bar';
        },
        template: '<div>Meta: {{ meta }}</div>'
    };
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nEcqFLkSTi1j7xf3u5H6)**

This directive uses an isolate scope, which, though it is technically a child of the controller's scope, it is isolated from it.